# Image freeze when a continuation is called

Tags: crash, pharo, continuation

I'm trying to test the continuation facility in Pharo, with this code(in the playground):

```
| cont f |
f:=[
    |i|
    i:=0.
    Continuation currentDo: [ :cc | cont:=cc ].
    i:=i+1.
].
f value. "1"
cont. "a Continuation"
```

However, as soon as I call the continuation saved in `cont`(replacing `cont.` by `cont value.`), the image freezes immediately, and I have to press `atl+.` to gain back control.

VM version: `VM: NBCoInterpreter NativeBoost-CogPlugin-GuillermoPolito.19 uuid: acc98e51-2fba-4841-a965-2975997bba66 May 15 2014 NBCogit NativeBoost-CogPlugin-GuillermoPolito.19 uuid: acc98e51-2fba-4841-a965-2975997bba66 May 15 2014 https://github.com/pharo-project/pharo-vm.git Commit: ed4a4f59208968a21d82fd2406f75c2c4de558b2 Date: 2014-05-15 18:23:04 +0200 By: Esteban Lorenzano <estebanlm@gmail.com> Jenkins build #14826`

Pharo version: `[version] 4.0 #40614`

Thanks.

Edit: I was stupid, didn't think this through...

Comment: well... not I was able to reproduce it, but adding the execution of the continuation (cont value) at the end of your script... you should add that part in your explaining script, otherwise is not comprensible. Anyway... let me see what can we do and I'll go back here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've effectively created an infinite loop by reevaluating the same code again and again. You can see that if you debug the code and step through it. The original context will always be restored and then evaluated starting with the first expression following the #currentDo: send. This is *exactly* what the continuation is supposed to do: save the current position in the execution and restart there later on.

Comment: I don't see how this is an infinite loop. When the continuation is executed, the execution starts at `i:=i+1`, then reach the end of the block. It should then return the result, no? There's no looping involved... However, putting a return at the end does work. Thanks.

Comment: Yes, you reach the end of the block *but in the context it was originally executed in*. That means, that `cont value` will also be executed again. And there's your loop.

Comment: Oh, I get it, sorry. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I do not have a Fedora to test, however I tried your code in Ubuntu, using this version of Pharo:

```
wget -O- get.pharo.org/40+vm | bash
./pharo-ui Pharo.image
```

and your code seems to work properly :(

In case this error persists, could you be more specific about the version of the vm you are using?:

```
./pharo Pharo.image --version
```

And the version of Pharo you are using?:

```
./pharo Pharo.image printVersion
```

Also, send us the `crash.dmp` file would help a lot.

Comment: VM version: `VM:    NBCoInterpreter NativeBoost-CogPlugin-GuillermoPolito.19 uuid: acc98e51-2fba-4841-a965-2975997bba66 May 15 2014
NBCogit NativeBoost-CogPlugin-GuillermoPolito.19 uuid: acc98e51-2fba-4841-a965-2975997bba66 May 15 2014
https://github.com/pharo-project/pharo-vm.git Commit: ed4a4f59208968a21d82fd2406f75c2c4de558b2 Date: 2014-05-15 18:23:04 +0200 By: Esteban Lorenzano <estebanlm@gmail.com> Jenkins build #14826`

  
  Pharo version: `[version] 4.0 #40614`.

Comment: And when I say "crash" I mean "freeze" and I need to kill it myself. There's no crash.dmp file.

Comment: Then is not a vm problem but an image one... you can try stoping the execution (just hit alt+. several times)... In any case, same code does not freezes for me, did you try that in a clean image or is an image with your modifications?

Comment: I've now tried it with a new installation and new image, still the same problem. I am able to unfreeze with `atl+.`, which shows me the code for the `restoreValues` method, with the following line highlighted:  
`to: context class instSize do: [:i | context instVarAt: i put: valueStream next].`

Comment: I'm also not able to reproduce your problem. What do you mean by "calling the continuation"? You aren't using the continuation in any way in the code you posted. Are you maybe doing more than what the code above does?

Comment: Calling the continuation => `cont value.`
As soon as I add "`value`" to the last line in the code above, it freezes.